# Select all cells except ones from first two columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Using Datatables I make all `<td>`s clickable. How can I tell the function to exclude cells from the first two rows as I don't want those cells to be clickable?

```
function () {
        var api = this.api();
        api.$('td').click( function () {
            api.search( this.innerHTML ).draw();
        });},
```

My table:

```
<table>
    <thead>
            <tr>                
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Surname</th>
                <th>etc</th>
                <th>etc</th>
            </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
            <?php foreach ($records as $record) : ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php e($record->name); ?></td>
                <td><?php e($record->surname) ?></td>
                <td><?php e($record->etc) ?></td>
                <td><?php e($record->cetc) ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jquery `gt()` to exclude first two rows, see below code

```
function () {
        var api = this.api();
        api.$('tr:gt(1) td').click( function () {
            api.search( this.innerHTML ).draw();
        });},
```

**[gt() API DOC](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) method for this:

```
api.$('td').not(":nth-child(1), :nth-child(2)").click( function () {
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lt` [selector](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) for this.

```
$('tr:lt(2) td').click(function() {
    api.search(this.innerHTML).draw();
});
```

This will bind events to td in the first 2 rows

**Edit**

If you want to bind events to the rows except the first 2 rows, use like this

```
$('tr:gt(1) td').click(function() {
        api.search(this.innerHTML).draw();
  });
```